# OpenMP implicit barrier

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Hi I am reading this website http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0054/ and for point number 17, it says that the code below without the barrier is wrong. Why ? I read at http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#BarrierDirectiveAndTheNowaitClause there is an implicit barrier at the end of each parallel block, and at the end of each sections, for and single statement, unless the nowait directive is used.

```
struct MyType 
{
    ~MyType();
};
MyType threaded_var;
#pragma omp threadprivate(threaded_var)
int main() 
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
           ...
           #pragma omp barrier // code is wrong without barrier.
    }    
}
```

Someone explain to me please. Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand [there is an implicit barrier at the end of a parallel region](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#ParallelRegion). Assuming that's true I think point number 17 is wrong in the link.

Comment: Just checked the OpenMP 4.5 specification and it says "There is an implicit barrier at the end of the parallel construct."

Comment: The specification says "The storage of all copies of a threadprivate variable is freed according to how static variables are handled in the base language, but at an unspecified point in the program."

Answer (score 0):

The linked web page is wrong about that point. There actually is an implicit barrier at the end of the parallel section.

Since the web site seems to have a Windows focus and MS only supports the OpenMP standard 2.0, it might be worth noting that this implicit barrier is not only in the current standard 4.5 but also in version 2.0:

> Upon completion of the parallel construct, the threads in the team
>   synchronize at an implicit barrier, [...]

http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/cspec20.pdf